# iBooks test for an internet connection with HTML widget

Tags: javascript, dashcode, ibooks

I created a widget in dashcode that embeds a YouTube video.  I'd like to test for an interent connection first and alert the user.  I embedded the YouTube widget into iBooks.  I'm guessing  at times some will not have an interent connection.

---

if I add:

```
 var online = window.navigator.onLine;
if (!online) {
alert("we are offline");
//console.log("We are offline!");
} else {
alert("we are online");
//console.log("We are online!");
}
```

And add that code to iBooks Author as a widget, the popup works fine, but there's no way to confirm the alert.  Basically, it locks up the iBook.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about ibook dashboard, but I wrote a heartbeat checker for my web app that could be used to confirm http connection, perhaps it could do what you need... [original post here](http://www.randomactsofsentience.com/2012/04/javascript-server-heartbeat.html)

You call the code with a URL to check, a max ttl, and a callback. If the page has not responded by the end of the ttl (in milliseconds) the callback is called with null else you get the status and the request object.

```
function heartbeat(url, ttl, callback) {
    // Confirms active connection to server by custom URL response
    //
    if (!url) {
        url = "http://www.yourwebsitehere.com/yourpage?someheartbeatcall";
        // Replace with specific server heartbeat location and query string for cache busting
    }
    if (!ttl) {
        ttl = 1000; // Custom timeout in milliseconds
        // Replace with specific server heartbeat location and query string for cache busting
    }
    // Create the Ajax object
    var ajaxRequest;
    try{
            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e){
                // Unable to create
                callback(null);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    // Set flag so only one pulse is recorded
    var called = false;
    // Make ajax call
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            if (!called) {
                called = true;
                callback(ajaxRequest.status, ajaxRequest);
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
    // Make ttl timeout call
    var ttlcatch = setTimeout(function(){
        if (!called) {
            called = true;
            callback(null);
        }
    }, ttl);
    return;
}

var foo = false;
heartbeat("http://www.google.com", 1000, function(pulse){alert(pulse);} )
```